# Connecting to SQL Server using domain user through Invoke-Command

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, powershell, windows-authentication

I have a console app on a remote server that connects to a SQL server using the credentials of the user executing the process.

When I execute the console app on the server itself using a service account it picks up the credentials just fine and logs into the database successfully. However, in order to fit this in my organization's automated process, I need to execute the console app from another server witch is running with a different service account that does not have access to the database.

It looks something like this:

`Automation server running under Automation Service account` (no access to db)

calls

`Application server under Application account and executes app` (has access to db)

To simplify this, I've replaced the console app with a simple Powershell script that tries to connect to the database. The result is the same.

```
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $ApplicationUser, $SecurePassword

Write-Host "Running executable" -ForegroundColor Green
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $applicationServer -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock { 
    Write-Host $(whoami)
    $SQLServer = "YourServerName"
    $SQLDBName = "YourDBName"
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $ServerName; Database = $DbName; Integrated Security=true;" 
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = 'StoredProcName'
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) 
    $SqlConnection.Close()
 }
```

The above script fails with the following error message
`"Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'."`

When I print the current user it claims that it is the application user, which should have access to the database.

It appears as if some of the user's credentials are stripped out when `Invoke-Command` is called but this is where my knowledge becomes limited.

Is there any kind of configuration that can enable this to work?

I am aware there's much easier alternatives but this is the infrastructure and security constraints I am limited by in my organization. (using a SQL user instead would've been a very easy alternative that we are not allowed)

Comment: Can you Access the database using SQL Server Management Studio?  The Power Shell is using Integrated Security which is using the User Windows Credential to access the database.  The database is probably setup to allow a Windows User Group to access the database and you may not be in the the User Group that has access to the database.  Using SSMS will make it easier to determine to cause of the issue.  Look at the login window of SSMS for the Server Name and instance of the database.  The power shell should be using same server and instance.

Comment: Yes, I can access the db using SSMS. The user definitely has access to the database

Comment: Then make sure the connection string in the power shell matches the login window of SSMS. $ServerName should be the Server/Instance in SSMS

Comment: They do match, and if I execute this directly on the server, without the extra hop it works fine. This is why I said it looks like parts of the credentials are being stripped out when running in the context of `Invoke-Command`

Comment: For windows credentials to work you need to setup the Windows Group Account on the Local and Remote Machines.  Talk to your MIS people to find out why on the server the users Group is not being recognized.  It looks like this is a Group Policy Issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
string connectionString = $"Data Source=_ServerName;Initial Catalog=_DatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;User ID=_Username;Password=_Paasword";
```

Hello try this ConnectingString, but first change this information with yours
`_ServerName`, `_DatabaseName`, `_Username`, `_Password`

Comment: As far as I am aware, `User ID` and `Password` only work for SQL users. This is a windows AD user. As mentioned, we are not allowed to user SQL users because of company policies. I had already tried this and it's not working